# $E[X^4]=0\Rightarrow E[X^2]=0$

Tags: probability, stochastic-processes

Let $X$ be a real random variable on a discrete probability space $(\Omega,P)$ so that the expected value of $X^5$ exists.

Prove or refute: $$E[X^4]=0 \Rightarrow  E[X^2]=0$$ and
$$E[X^5]=0 \Rightarrow  E[X^3]=0$$

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Comment: $E[X^{2k}]=0$ iff $X=0$ almost surely.

Comment: @LordSharktheUnknown For real-valued r.v.s. I like my random variables to be uniform in $\{1,i\}$.

Comment: @newbie: is there any assumption on $X$? Real-valued, for instance?

Comment: Thank you for pointing that problem out,  I edited my question. Next time I will be more precise about where exactly I need help and put a finer point to the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Notice that
$$\mathbb{E}[X^k] = \sum_{\omega \in \Omega} X(\omega)^k \cdot  \mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})$$
If $k$ is even and $X$ is real-valued, then since $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\}) \ge 0$ and $X(\omega)^k \ge 0$ for all $\omega$, the only way this can be equal to zero is if $X^k(\omega)=0$ when $\mathbb{P}(\{\omega\})>0$, in which case $\mathbb{E}[X^k]=0$ for all even values of $k$.

If $k$ is odd or $X$ is allowed to be complex-valued, then you should be able to cook up some counterexamples.

For example, $X$ is real-valued, take $\Omega = \{ 0, 1 \}$ with $\mathbb{P}(\{0\})=p$ and $\mathbb{P}(\{1\})=1-p$ for your favourite value of $p$ except $0,\frac{1}{2},1$. Define $X(0)=1$ and define $X(1)$ to be whatever value makes $\mathbb{E}[X^5]=0$. You'll find that $\mathbb{E}[X^3] \ne 0$.

If $X$ is complex-valued, a similar trick using $\Omega = \{1, i\}$ should yield a counterexample to $\mathbb{E}[X^4]=0 \Rightarrow \mathbb{E}[X^2]=0$, cf. Clement's comments.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the random variable is not assumed to be real-valued. $X^2$ and $\lvert X\rvert^2$ are not the same thing in general...

Comment: For instance, take $X$ uniform on the two-element set $\{1,i\}$. $\mathbb{E}[X^2] = \frac{1}{2}\left(1^2+i^2\right)=0$.

Comment: Sure, if $X$ is complex then this obviously fails, in which case the argument when $X$ is odd applies. Perhaps you'll remove your downvote now that I've clarified this in my answer.

Comment: I did. But I'd actually like the OP to clarify their question...

Answer (score 2):

For the first one (assuming that $X$ is real valued r.v.. And BTW, why have you mentioned $Y$?), note that 
$$
Var(X^2) = \mathbb{E}(X^2- \mathbb{E}X^2)^2 = \mathbb{E}X^4 - (\mathbb{E}X^2)^2\ge 0,  
$$ 
hence if $\mathbb{E}X^4 = 0$, thus $\mathbb{E}X^2 =0$ as well.